# Converting Paulson's parser combinators to Haskell

Tags: haskell, sml, ml

I am trying to convert the code from Paulson's ML for the working programmer book chapter 9, Writing Interpreters for the λ-Calculus.
I was wondering if anyone can help me translate this to Haskell. 
I'm struggling to understand the syntax.

```
fun list ph = ph -- repeat ("," $-- ph) >> (op::);

fun pack ph = "(" $-- list ph --$")"       >> #1
              | empty;
```

Comment: The above involves undefined operators such as `>>` that have no built-in meaning in SML. If you are using some parsing library, perhaps you could specify what that library is.

Comment: Looks like it might be the same as 'writing interpreters for the lambda calculus chapter' of Paulson's ML for the working programmer, but can't help with the haskell.

Comment: Yes I am trying to convert the code from Paulson's ML for the working programmer book. I am quite new programming, so I don't understand it.

Comment: Yes I am trying to convert the code from Paulson's ML for the working programmer book. I am quite new programming, so I don't understand it. its on page 363 in this book https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=XppZdaDs7e0C&pg=PA357&lpg=PA357&dq=seldom+parsing+ml&source=bl&ots=y01aoQrqqC&sig=pTWWMzTPLWY2NeohfScub8l2jss&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4i-yZ95zTAhXlJMAKHagZAEwQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=seldom%20parsing%20ml&f=false@matt @JohnColeman

Comment: Did you read the previous 362 pages? If not, that would be a good place to start.

Comment: @JohnColeman I had look at previous pages but I'm still not sure how I would convert that to Haskell

Comment: Are you new to programming in general or just to programming in SML?

Comment: I've been working with Haskell a bit but I'm new to SML  @IonuțG.Stan

Comment: Your first step should probably be to understand what the operators mean,  but given an implementation of the operators (SML implementation is on page 365), the result should look almost identical. You "only" need to learn enough SML (and Haskell) to implement the operators.

Answer (score 4):

In porting this code to Haskell, I see two challenges: One is rewriting the combinators so they use the type *Either SyntaxError* rather than exceptions for flow control, and the other is preserving the modularity of ML's functors. That is, writing a parser combinator library that is modular with regards to what keywords / symbols / tokenizer it should use.

While the ML code has the two

```ml
functor Lexical (Keyword: KEYWORD) : LEXICAL
functor Parsing (Lex: LEXICAL) : PARSE
```

you could start by having

```hs
data Keyword = Keyword
  { alphas :: [String]
  , symbols :: [String]
  }

data Token
  = Key String
  | Id String
  deriving (Show, Eq)

lex :: Keyword -> String -> [Token]
lex kw s = ...
  where
    alphaTok :: String -> Token
    alphaTok a | a `elem` alphas kw = Key a
               | otherwise = Id a
    ...
```

The ML code uses the types *string* and *substring* while Haskell's *String* is actually a *[Char]*. The lexer functions would look a little different because ML's `String.getc` could simply be the pattern match `c : ss1` in Haskell, etc.

Paulson's parsers have type *[Token] → (τ, [Token])* but allow for exceptions. The Haskell parsers could have type *[Token] → Either SyntaxError (τ, [Token])*:

```hs
newtype SyntaxError = SyntaxError String
  deriving Show

newtype Parser a = Parser { runParser :: [Token] -> Either SyntaxError (a, [Token]) }

err :: String -> Either SyntaxError b
err msg = Left (SyntaxError msg)
```

The operators `id`, `$`, `||`, `!!`, `--` and `>>` need new names, since they collide with a bunch of built-in operators and single-line comments. Ideas for names could be: `ident`, `kw`, `|||`, `+++` and `>>>`. I would skip implementing the `!!` operator initially.

Here are two combinators implemented a little differently,

```
ident :: Parser String
ident = Parser f
  where
    f :: [Token] -> Either SyntaxError (String, [Token])
    f (Id x : toks) = Right (x, toks)
    f (Key x : _) = err $ "Identifier expected, got keyword '" ++ x ++ "'"
    f [] = err "Identifier expected, got EOF"

    (+++) :: Parser a -> Parser b -> Parser (a, b)
    (+++) pa pb = Parser $ \toks1 -> do (x, toks2) <- runP pa toks1
                                        (y, toks3) <- runP pb toks2
                                        return ((x, y), toks3)
    ...
```

Some final remarks:

- Read the paper [Monadic Parsing in Haskell](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/%7Epszgmh/pearl.pdf) (Hutton, Meijer).
- You may be interested in [SimpleParse](https://github.com/kfl/simpleparse/blob/master/SimpleParse.hs) by Ken Friis Larsen, an educational parser combinator library that is a simplification of [ReadP](http://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/8.0.1/docs/html/libraries/base-4.9.0.0/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html) by Koen Claessen, since its source code is very easy to read. They are both non-deterministic.
- If you're interested in *using* parser combinators in Haskell, rather than porting some old-fashioned library for the learning experience, I encourage you too look at [Megaparsec](https://mrkkrp.github.io/megaparsec/tutorials/parsing-simple-imperative-language.html) (tutorial), a modern fork of Parsec. The implementation is a little complex.
- None of these three libraries (SimpleParse, ReadP, Megaparsec) split lexing and parsing into two separate steps. Rather, they simply build small tokenizing parsers that implicitly eat meaningless whitespace. (See the [`token` combinator](https://github.com/kfl/simpleparse/blob/master/SimpleParse.hs#L162-L163) in SimpleParse, for example.) However, Megaparsec does allow an arbitrary token type, whether that is `Char` or some token you have lexed.